# Android Recycler View two Sections

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to use recycler view with two sections with a simple header.
Each section data ie, list content will be coming from two different webservice.
I can able to show first section with header. But I have no idea on how to create a second section with different data in the same RecycleView.Adapter .

Can anybody give a suggestion to handle this ?

Comment: I just wrote an [article](https://medium.com/@carsonholzy/the-easiest-fastest-and-best-recyclerview-with-kotlin-for-your-copy-pasting-pleasure-581e5cacc432) on how to do this. With about 15 lines of code, and copying 3 classes, you can turn 2 lists into sections on a recyclerview with headers.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my library on Github, can be used to easily create sections:
[RecyclerAdapter & Easy Section](https://github.com/MaximeJallu/RecyclerAdapter-Java#sectiondecorator-recycler-with-linearlayout-or-gridlayout)

```
mRecylerView.setLayoutManager(...);
/*create Adapter*/
RecyclerAdapter<Customer> baseAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter<>(...);
/*create sectioned adapter. the Adapter type can be RecyclerView.Adapter*/
SectionedAdapter<String, RecyclerAdapter> adapter = new SectionedAdapter<>(SectionViewHolder.class, baseAdapter);
/*add your sections*/
sectionAdapter.addSection(0/*position*/, "Title Section 1");
/*attach Adapter to RecyclerView*/
mRecylerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the AdvancedSectionAdapter from [HERE](https://github.com/chitanka/android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/info/chitanka/android/ui/adapters/AdvancedSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.java). All you need to do is override the following six abstract methods:

```
public abstract int getGroupCount();

public abstract int getChildCount(int group);

public abstract SectionVH onCreateSectionViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);

public abstract ChildVH onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);

public abstract void onBindSectionViewHolder(SectionVH holder, int position, List<Object> payloads);

public abstract void onBindChildViewHolder(ChildVH holder, int belongingGroup, int position, List<Object> payloads);
```

The rest is taken care of for you. You have to specify the number of parent sections `getGroupCount`, the number of children for parent `getChildCount` and then you need to create and bind the parent and the children of the parent.

You can create a simple SortedMap of a String, List<> where the String keys are the sections and the List are the children. (Why SortedMap? Because it keeps your keys sorted and not random as HashMap).

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommended [SectionedRecyclerView](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) library.

1. It supports both header and footer.
2. It supports different states liked LOADING, LOADED, EMPTY, ... So, while you are waiting respond from webservice, you can easily display a progress bar, by just switching the Section state to LOADING. Once the data is ready, you can switch to LOADED state.
3. The library comes with extensive unit testing to ensure its code quality.

This is the library, which I use in real-world app.

As you can see, it has header, footer and multiple content rows.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a RecyclerView inside a scrollview? Do you realise there is no performance benefit in doing that? You should just use a scrollview

Comment: This is RecyclerView. Nothing to do with ScrollView.

Comment: Are you saying "Earning history" is a header in the recyclerview then?

Comment: It's just that in the image you post, I don't see an example of a header or footer in a recycler view